# Feb 2017 Tango Core breaks older apps? (C API)

Tags: google-project-tango

The February 2017 update of the Tango Core seem to break apps built with older versions of the SDK. Specifically, TangoSupport_updatePointCloud() seem to fail on our app built with Dec 2016 Biyelgee C SDK.

We're wondering if anyone else is getting similar issue and whether is this a legitimate Tango Core issue?

EDIT:
Confirmed that rolling back to previous version Tango Core get us back to working state.

Answer (score 1):

If using the JAVA API:  Yes there is a breaking change, it is [referenced here on the release notes for eisa](https://developers.google.com/tango/release-notes).
That link gives you the steps to migrate to Eisa and fix the problem.

> Warning: This change requires existing Java applications using depth
>   to recompile against the E-release SDK to continue working properly. ... 
>   If your app is using the Java APIs with depth, you must recompile your app with the latest Tango SDK and push an update to Play Store. Recompiling may require some code changes, given the Java callback changes (see below) and earlier deprecation of XYZij in favor of XYZC.

Comment: Yes I saw that, but we're using C API.